# Google cloud storage does not let me remove bucket with huge data

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have around 200 gb of data on a google cloud coldline bucket. When i try to remove it, it keeps preparing forever.

Any way to remove the bucket ?

Comment: Are you doing it through the Console or with the *gsutil* tool?

Comment: I am trying with console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the *gsutil* tool if you have been trying with the Console and it did not work. To do so, you can just open Google Cloud Shell (most left button in the top right corner of the Console) and type a command like:

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

It may take a while, but with the `-r` flag you will be deleting first the contents of the bucket recursively, and later delete the bucket itself. The `-m` flag performs parallel removes, to speed up the process.

Comment: yeah well, the only option left is this, though it takes ALOT of time as there are many little files, like millions

Also it is good to use the -m flag, so it deletes in parallel, you could update your post

Comment: You are right, I missed that. Thanks for tip, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also set a lifecycle policy of 0 days, which will wipe out the whole bucket. But you'll have to wait a little while for it to trigger.

Comment: Yeah that's something i missed, it is still better than deleting with iteration, what we did, and it took around a day or so